# Upload an image to filesystem, rename it and set it as Profile Picture for current user

Tags: 8, users, files

I have the external link of an image where I am trying to:

1. Upload the image to filesystem.
2. Rename the image.
3. Set the owner of the image to current user.
4. Set the image as Profile Picture for current user.

**So far I have:**

```
$full_name = "John Smith";
$picture_url = "https://scontent.fbey14-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/14054356_124897527960923_50194821455451882_o.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=P4i5oscJf0IAX_KFCfR&_nc_ht=scontent.fbey14-1.fna&oh=c13b6b2d8712db359f3be5e1ec835340&oe=5EF2B1A4";

// Download the picture to local filesystem.
$profile_pic = system_retrieve_file($picture_url, "public://profile-pictures", TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Get the Profile Pic ID.
$profile_pic_id = $profile_pic->id();

// Load the image.
$picture = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($profile_pic_id);

// Rename the image.
$picture->setFilename("$full_name.jpg");
// Set the owner of the profile picture file.
$picture->setOwner($current_user);

// Save the image.
$picture->save();

$current_user->set('user_picture', $profile_pic_id);
$current_user->save();
```

The image is indeed uploaded to filesystem under `public://profile-pictures`, also is successfully set as profile picture of the current user.

and the filename of the image at `/user/*/edit` edit page is set to: **john-smith.jpg**, however, the filename of the image at `public://profile-pictures` is **14054356_124897527960923_50194821455451882_o.jpg** while I am expecting it to be **john-smith.png** !

How to rename the image at the filesystem ?

and does `$picture->setOwner($current_user)` will set the owner of the image to the current user ?

Comment: Not sure if changing *.jpg to *.png is the best idea.

Comment: I guess it's a typo in the question, because you cannot get a PNG file with the code shown in the question.

Comment: @leymannx the image I am trying to get is for Facebook profile picture which as per Facebook documentation will always be of type '.jpg' (FB API always serves JPG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Clive you can do it that why, and also you can download the image directly with the full_name.
To do so just change the line:

```
$profile_pic = system_retrieve_file($picture_url, "public://profile-pictures", TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

by

```
$profile_pic = system_retrieve_file($picture_url, "public://profile-pictures/$full_name.jpg", TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

and remove the line:

```
$picture->setFilename("$full_name.jpg");
```

Comment: your code just renamed the file as expected !
When I upload the image using "Upload" Button, I see this message: `The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions of 500x500 pixels. The new dimensions of the resized image are 500x500 pixels.` is there a quick code I must add for the resizing to work or it is better to ask a separated question for this ?

Comment: you can change the user profiles image field configuration by going to **admin/config/people/accounts/fields/user.user.user_picture** and change **Maximum image resolution**

Comment: you got me wrong, I am aware about the **Maximum image resolution** at **admin/config/people/accounts/fields/user.user.user_picture** but my question: When programmatically uploading the image, the **Maximum image resolution** settings will take effect ?

Comment: I guess you should ask separate question, to how prevent **Maximum image resolution** on profile image programmatically !

Answer (score 0):

`setFilename` just updates the field value on the file entity, it doesn't move anything on disk. You can do both in one go with [`file_move()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_move/8.8.x):

```
$dest = "public://profile-pictures/$full_name.jpg";
if (file_move($picture, $dest) === FALSE) {
  // Something went wrong.
}
```